# Changing transparency and blur in yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

OSX Yosemite uses blurred backgrounds that are not useful.  The blurred image in Dashboard is not useful.  Is it possible to change the blur to have clearer images? Is it possible to change the transparency for the translucent images to be more transparent?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the transparency off if it's bugging you, but it’s an on/off toggle. There’s no way to configure the “amount” of transparency.

In the **Accessibility** panel of **System Preferences**, there's a **Reduce transparency** tickbox. Checking this box will turn off all the transparency throughout the system.

[image]

<sup>Screenshot from [the 512 Pixels Yosemite review](http://www.512pixels.net/blog/2014/10/os-x-yosemite-review)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP really wants, since the question asks how to make the images *more* transparent.

Comment: Yes, I was asking how to make the images more transparent.

Comment: the answer is still correct - "There’s no way to configure the “amount” of transparency."

Comment: @Tetsujin note that I clarified that after G-Man's comment. The first answer was a bit sloppy.